# Error:- too many values to unpack (expected 2) python function

Tags: python

My Code:-

```
Videos10k=[{'title': '', 'titleWords': ['...','...'], 'titleLength': 10, 'likes': 86, 'disLikes': 5, 'views': 2202, 'creator': '...', 'description': '...'}]
def getavg(number, array=[]):
    views_avg = 0
    for idx, Video in array:
        views = Video["views"]
        views_avg = views_avg + views

    views_avg = views_avg / len(array)
    print("Average views for " + number + " " + views_avg)


getavg("10k", Videos10k)
```

I am getting this error.
Error:-

> in getavg
> for idx, Video in array: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: Not related to your question, but check https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/4046632 Don't use mutable default arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`enumerate` function gives to index number.

Change your code like below

```py
for idx, Video in enumerate(array):
```

Comment: Just to mention that actually `idx` is never used anywhere else in the code, i.e. it's redundant.

Comment: @buran exception says that `in getavg for idx, Video in array: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`. Even you are not using `idx`, code expects.

Comment: Exactly - one way to solve it is to add enumerate, the other (if idx is not needed) is to remove idx, like @puhuk did in their answer, instead of just keep the redundant idx.

Answer (score 6):

You need to get item in array with just Video, not with idx, Video

```
Videos10k=[{'title': '', 'titleWords': ['...','...'], 'titleLength': 10, 'likes': 86, 'disLikes': 5, 'views': 2202, 'creator': '...', 'description': '...'}]
def getavg(number, array=[]):
    views_avg = 0
    for Video in array:
        views = Video["views"]
        views_avg = views_avg + float(views)

    views_avg = views_avg / len(array)
    print("Average views for " + str(number) + " " + str(views_avg))
```

Or you can change to like this

```
for idex, Video in enumerate(array):
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to loop through the index of array you can use **enumerate** like this :

```
for idx, Video in enumerate(array):
```

or use **zip** :

```
for idx,Video in zip(range(len(array)),array):
```

in your code you never used idx so you don't need it .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep things Simple, Keep Videos10k as a dict and have the function handle the different type() of input.

```
Videos10k={'title': '', 'titleWords': ['...','...'], 'titleLength': 10, 'likes': 86, 'disLikes': 5, 'views': 2202, 'creator': '...', 'description': '...'}

def getAvg(number,array):
    if type(array) != list:
        print('Average Views For {}: {}'.format(number,array/len([array])))
    else:
        print('Average Views For {}: {}'.format(number,array/len(array)))



getAvg("10k", Videos10k['views'])
```